# Why variables setted inside Enum.each is not saved?

Tags: enums, elixir

I'm trying to set a value to a variable inside a function in `Enum.each`, but at the end of loop, variable is empty and I don't know exactly why this behaviour.

Code:

```
base = "master"
candidates = ["stream", "pigeons", "maters"]

return = []
Enum.each(candidates, fn candidate ->
    cond do
        String.length(base) == String.length(candidate) ->
            return = return ++ [candidate]
        true ->
            true
    end
end)
IO.inspect return
```

At this example, `return` is expected to be `["stream", "maters"]`, but instead, it is only an empty list: `[]`

My question is why this happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When dealing with languages like Elixir, it is better to think in terms of "values" and "names" instead of "variables".

The reason you cannot do what you want is that Elixir has ["lexical scoping"](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/lexical-scoping-static-scoping). 
When you assign to a "variable", you create a new value in the inner scope. You never change the "value" of a "name" defined in the outer scope.

(you probably can get what you want with `Enum.filter/2`, but I'm guessing this is just an illustrative example)

EDIT:

As of today, Elixir will allow you to write something like this:

```
if condition_that_evals_to_false do
  x = 1
else
  x = 2
end

IO.inspect x # => 2
```

```

But this will be deprecated in Elixir 1.3

Answer (score 5):

Any reason why you don't just filter?

Anyways it seems like you're trying to mutate the value of return which is not possible with Elixir.

```
base = "master"
candidates = ["stream", "pigeon", "maters"]
result = Enum.filter(candidates, fn(candidate) ->
  length(candidate) == length(base)
end

IO.inspect result
```

Edit: I'd also like to add that based on your logic, all of the candidates would be returned

Comment: You are correct about all being returned. I did make a typo in this example and already edited.

Comment: About your logic, yes, it is much better than mine, thanks! :)

Comment: My issue is solved with your logic, but the question still needs to be answered. Because of this, I can't choose your answer to close the question. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Renan Ranelli has given an answer that should satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, since I've never worked with the language, but a couple things spring to mind:

`String.length(base) == String.length(candidate)` can be equivalent to true, which is already a pattern in your set.

It could also be a scope issue with the return variable. It could be that the local return is hiding the global return. You could check this by outputting return every iteration. Each iteration the return should contain a single entry.

Comment: you are correct about the local value being different than global.

Answer (score -4):

This is a bug. From [Elixir's documentation](http://elixir-lang.readthedocs.io/en/latest/technical/scoping.html#case-like-clauses):

> Note: due to a bug in the 0.12.x series, cond‘s conditions actually
>   leak bindings to the surrounding scope. This should be fixed in
>   0.13.1.

You should use filtering like @{Christopher Yammine} suggested.

Comment: You're about 9 months late.  Elixir is currently on 1.2.5